# Move XML element to a specific position

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Good day, I need to move the all the `ComposedBlock` tag to the last position of `TextBlock` the example XML is below.

This is the XML input:

```
<parent>
<ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000001" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727">
    <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000001_SUB" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727" />
</ComposedBlock>
<ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000002" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730">
    <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000002_SUB" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730" />
</ComposedBlock>
<TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000006" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
    <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000028" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120">
      <String ID="P1_ST0000165" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1680" WIDTH="63" HEIGHT="86" CONTENT="ijt" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000156" HPOS="2602" VPOS="1766" />
    </TextLine>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000011" HPOS="4406" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1724" HEIGHT="1003" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
    <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000083" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1714" HEIGHT="120">
      <String ID="P1_ST0000532" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="346" HEIGHT="91" CONTENT="Change" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000513" HPOS="4757" VPOS="5261" />
      <String ID="P1_ST0000533" HPOS="4776" VPOS="5198" WIDTH="230" HEIGHT="63" CONTENT="yo0ur" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000514" HPOS="5006" VPOS="5261" />
    </TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</parent>
```

and this is the desired output:

```
<parent>
<TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000006" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
    <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000028" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120">
      <String ID="P1_ST0000165" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1680" WIDTH="63" HEIGHT="86" CONTENT="ijt" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000156" HPOS="2602" VPOS="1766" />
    </TextLine>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000011" HPOS="4406" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1724" HEIGHT="1003" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
    <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000083" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1714" HEIGHT="120">
      <String ID="P1_ST0000532" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="346" HEIGHT="91" CONTENT="Change" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000513" HPOS="4757" VPOS="5261" />
      <String ID="P1_ST0000533" HPOS="4776" VPOS="5198" WIDTH="230" HEIGHT="63" CONTENT="yo0ur" />
      <SP ID="P1_SP0000514" HPOS="5006" VPOS="5261" />
    </TextLine>
</TextBlock>
<ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000001" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727">
    <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000001_SUB" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727" />
</ComposedBlock>
<ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000002" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730">
    <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000002_SUB" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730" />
</ComposedBlock>
</parent>
```

and here is my code:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(reader);
IEnumerable<XElement> wd =
    from el in doc.Descendants("ComposedBlock").ToList()
    select el;

foreach (XElement el in wd)
{
    //what do i need to do here?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with xml linq

```
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement parent = doc.DescendantsAndSelf("parent").FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> wd = parent.Elements("ComposedBlock").ToList();

            foreach (XElement composedBlock in wd)
            {
                composedBlock.ReplaceWith(null);
            }
            parent.Add(wd);
```

Comment: Why not call Remove, instead of ReplaceWith(null) ?

Comment: I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

its not a very good code, but it works

i created a list that uses XElement as datatype. where i add the elements i need to transfer

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(alto);
                var a = doc.Descendants("TextBlock").Last();
                foreach (var item in lstpc)
                {
                    a.AddAfterSelf(new XElement(item));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB it would look like this

```
    For Each el As XElement In xe...<ComposedBlock>.ToList
        xe.Elements.LastOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(el)
        el.Remove()
    Next
```

using this to load and / or test

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a file
    'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)
    ' for testing
    xe = <parent>
             <ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000001" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727">
                 <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000001_SUB" HPOS="6278" VPOS="1670" WIDTH="3610" HEIGHT="2727"/>
             </ComposedBlock>
             <ComposedBlock ID="P1_CB0000002" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730">
                 <GraphicalElement ID="P1_CB0000002_SUB" HPOS="653" VPOS="1728" WIDTH="1689" HEIGHT="730"/>
             </ComposedBlock>
             <TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000006" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
                 <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000028" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1675" WIDTH="1200" HEIGHT="120">
                     <String ID="P1_ST0000165" HPOS="2539" VPOS="1680" WIDTH="63" HEIGHT="86" CONTENT="ijt"/>
                     <SP ID="P1_SP0000156" HPOS="2602" VPOS="1766"/>
                 </TextLine>
             </TextBlock>
             <TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000011" HPOS="4406" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1724" HEIGHT="1003" LANG="en" STYLEREFS="PAR_JUSTIFIED">
                 <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000083" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="1714" HEIGHT="120">
                     <String ID="P1_ST0000532" HPOS="4411" VPOS="5170" WIDTH="346" HEIGHT="91" CONTENT="Change"/>
                     <SP ID="P1_SP0000513" HPOS="4757" VPOS="5261"/>
                     <String ID="P1_ST0000533" HPOS="4776" VPOS="5198" WIDTH="230" HEIGHT="63" CONTENT="yo0ur"/>
                     <SP ID="P1_SP0000514" HPOS="5006" VPOS="5261"/>
                 </TextLine>
             </TextBlock>
         </parent>
```